# how to use jq to filter an object based on it's key:value pair?

Tags: json, filter, jq

Assuming this is the input

```
>echo '{"A": {"x": 1}, "B": {"x":2}, "C":{"x":3}}' | jq '.'
{
  "A": {
    "x": 1
  },
  "B": {
    "x": 2
  },
  "C": {
    "x": 3
  }
}
```

I would like to get the return object of `"x" == 2`.
The only way i know of how to achieve that is thru this

```
>echo '{"A": {"x": 1}, "B": {"x":2}, "C":{"x":3}}' | jq '.[] | select(.x==2)'
{
  "x": 2
}
```

Is there a way to have jq return me like this instead?

```
{
  "B": {
    "x": 2
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use map_values :

```
map_values(select(.x == 2))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with_entries(select(.value.x == 2))
```

Comment: Thanks. I've found the same answer too :)   `>echo '{"A": {"x": 3}, "B": {"x":2}, "C":{"x":3}}' | jq 'to_entries |.[] | select(.value.x==3) | [.] | from_entries'`